# How do I acquire the value of an observable boolean?

Tags: rx-swift

I've created an 'observable' boolean variable that is to be bound (via .bind) to a UISwitch.  
(The traditional imperative model would be easier; but I'm trying to learn to nuances of rxCocoa)

I'm not sure what to do here; I'm basing my logic on some sample code working with Strings. 
I used 'just' because I'm only interested in the one variable's toggled value.

As you can see, the closure parameter is too vague.  
What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var IOButton = Variable(false)
var isOn: Observable<Bool> = IOButton.asObservable()
```

Then, with your UISwitch:

```
isOn
   .bind(to: switch.rx.isOn )
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

UPDATE 1:

Now you can `subscribe` to `isOn`

```
isOn
  .subscribe(onNext: { 
     print($0)
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.   I want to be able to execute a func() per switch event.

Comment: You can subscribe to `isOn` too. Please check the update 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe I came up with the solution:

```
// On/Off Switch

let onOffSwitch = Variable(true)

onOffSwitch.asObservable()
   .subscribe (onNext: { switchValue in
       print("This is new SwitchValue: \(switchValue)")
   }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

aSwitch.rx.isOn.bind(to: onOffSwitch)
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

'aSwitch' is the UISwitch.

When I toggle the switch, I get the following:

```
This is new SwitchValue: true
This is new SwitchValue: false
This is new SwitchValue: true
This is new SwitchValue: false
```

From this paradigm I can insert a self.func() within the closure instead of the print() so I can do stuff per switch; versus the familiar @IBAction.

Comment: While this solution may work, it is usually wise to avoid using `Variable`, since it leads to stateful design, which reactive programming tries to avoid. It's a trap that is easy to fall into when coming from imperative programming. Look into this article for some tips on a stateless design: http://rx-marin.com/post/rxswift-state-with-scan/